# Need help with adding jQuery script to WP and calling script to page

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I've written a pretty simple jQuery script, and I don't know how to call it. It's in its own directory.

First, how do I register it, and then how do I enqueue it?

I assume that's the order it's done in, and that registering it basically means that it's available for use, and that enqueuing it applies it.

I know that I have to add code to `functions.php`, but not sure exactly what. I've read a few things that haven't made it any clearer. For instance, WP.org says if I want to use Google's jQuery library, then I should deregister WP's install. Someone on this forum says don't deregister it. Using WP's version is fine, so this is what I have in `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_register_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

I also don't know how to call it on a page. What code, specifically, would I add to the page's WYSIWYG to get the script to work? Here's what I have on the page now:

```
<?php wp_register_script( $resize_fade.js, $http://www.mysite.com/subdirectory/wp-content/js/, ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i usally first deregister to avoid duplicates, then register it and enqueue it like so:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Hope this helps,
Sagive.

Comment: I'd had that code before. My real concern is what code to put in my page to make it work. And does it go in the WYSIWYG editor, or directly into a .php page? And is the code I wrote correct?

Comment: You put this entire script as is in your functions.php in your template files... Thats all. it would load jquery at the background of each wordpress file.

Comment: Including the other code I'm asking about, where it has the name and path to the script?

Comment: My script includes everything you need... it would work just like that. if you want to use your own jquery (which is a bit slower) you should replace "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" which the url of your file. but i would reccomend you use it like it is.

Comment: I have that. Now, how do I make the script I wrote work on the page? Did you see it? I tried to add **<?php wp_register_script( $resize_fade.js, $http://www.mysite.com/subdirectory/wp-content/js/, ); ?>** to the page, not knowing wether or not that was right.  BTW, I do appreciate your help...

Comment: if you want to inlcude your own script with a unique name you dont need all that and can just put a call to it in header.php

Comment: That script i wrote up there is just to avoid duplicate jQuery becouse many plugins call for it and 2 jquery's might and usally cause a lot of problems..

Comment: Okay, I got it. Did some research. The call has to go after wp_head().

Comment: gr8 man.. glad you got everything working ;)